# Permantly provide path to the headers and linker flags in OpenCV Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, pkg-config

I have OpenCV 4.5.1 installed in Linux. But each time I restart I have to separely provide path to the headers and linker flags. and then compile ?
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/home/parallels/opencv4.5-custom/lib/pkgconfig
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4

and then
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)

I just want to run the g++ comand each time

Comment: pkg-config usage issue. perhaps https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ would be a better fit? -- nobody runs `g++` manually. everyone uses some kind of build system. at least `make`. additionally, build files can be generated using `cmake` or other tools.

Comment: That's traditionally done using a `Makefile` which captures all your build settings and allows you to just type `make` to get it all built, and potentially installed.